# How to pass JWT bearer token to another request?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, http-status-code-403, bearer-token

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering an issue in my Spring Boot web application where I'm receiving a 403 Forbidden error after successfully logging in or registering. Here's a brief overview of my setup:

```
Spring Boot is used for the backend.
Thymeleaf is used for server-side templating.
JavaScript handles client-side interactions.
I'm implementing JWT token-based authentication.
```

**Problem:**

- Context:
  I've successfully implemented user registration and login functionality.
  Upon successful login or registration, the user is redirected to /main.html.
- Issue:
  Despite successful authentication, I'm getting a `403 Forbidden` error when trying to access /main.html.
- Security Configuration:
  I've configured Spring Security to handle authentication and authorization.
  I'm using JWT tokens for authentication.

  Code Snippets:

**SecurityConfiguration:**

```
package com.logistics.logisticsCompany.config;

import com.logistics.logisticsCompany.entities.users.User;
import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{ //1:55:40
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers( "/api/v1/auth/**", "/login", "/register")   //todo: change whitelist pages
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                        //.and() of course .and() is deprecated, because why not
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)) //spring will create new session for each request
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationService:**

```
package com.logistics.logisticsCompany.auth;

import com.logistics.logisticsCompany.config.JwtService;
import com.logistics.logisticsCompany.entities.users.User;
import com.logistics.logisticsCompany.repository.UserRepository;
import com.logistics.logisticsCompany.repository.UserRoleRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Set;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {

    private final UserRepository repository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;  //todo: add a bean -fixed - the bean wasn't public in ApplicationConfig
    private  final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest request) {
        var user = User.builder()
                .username(request.getUsername())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()))
                .userRoleList(Set.of(userRoleRepository.findUserRoleById(1))) // Add the desired role to the set// todo: find a way to put
                .build();
        repository.save(user);
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)        //1:52:21
                .build();
        
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {     //login authentication
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getUsername(),
                        request.getPassword()
                )
        );
        var user = repository.findByUsername(request.getUsername());
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**auth.js:**

```
// auth.js

// Function to handle success response from authentication or registration
function handleSuccess(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json().then(data => {
            const token = data.token;
            if (token) {
                // Save the token to localStorage
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                // Redirect to a specified page or handle as needed
                redirectToPage("/main.html");
            } else {
                console.error('Token not found in response:', data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        return response.json().then(data => {
            console.error('Error:', data);
        });
    }
}

// Function to redirect to a specified page
function redirectToPage(page) {
    window.location.href = page;
}
function authenticateUser() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    // Construct JSON payload
    var payload = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    };

    // Log the token before making the request
    console.log("Token in localStorage:", localStorage.getItem('token'));

    // Send the JSON payload to the authentication endpoint with bearer token
    fetch("/api/v1/auth/authenticate", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token')
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
        .then(handleSuccess)
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

    // Prevent form submission
    return false;
}



function registerUser() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    // Construct JSON payload
    var payload = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    };

    // Send the JSON payload to the registration endpoint
    fetch("/api/v1/auth/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                // Registration successful, you might not get a token here
                console.log("Registration successful");
                // Redirect to login page or handle as needed
            } else {
                // Registration failed, handle errors
                console.error('Error during registration:', response.status);
                return response.json();
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data); // Handle additional registration response here
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

    // Prevent form submission
    return false;
}

function sendAuthenticatedRequest() {
    var token = localStorage.getItem('token');  // Retrieve the JWT token from localStorage

    if (!token) {
        console.error('Token not found. User is not authenticated.');
        // Handle the case where the user is not authenticated, maybe redirect to login
        return;
    }

    // Construct the headers with Authorization Bearer Token
    var headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    // Make a GET request to /main.html with Authorization header
    fetch('http://localhost:8082/main.html', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                // Handle the successful response, maybe display the content of main.html
                return response.text();
            } else {
                // Handle the case where the server responds with an error (e.g., 403)
                console.error('Error:', response.statusText);
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Response from /main.html:', data);
            // You can update your UI with the content of main.html here
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

// Call the function to send the authenticated request
sendAuthenticatedRequest();
```

**AuthenticationController:**

```
package com.logistics.logisticsCompany.auth;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {
    private final AuthenticationService service;
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> responseResponseEntity(@RequestBody RegisterRequest request
    ){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.register(request));
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticationResponseResponseEntity(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request
    ){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.authenticate(request));
    }
}
```

**login.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="src/main/resources/static/js/auth.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container mt-5">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="max-width: 300px; text-align: center;">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <br>
        <form th:action="@{/api/v1/auth/authenticate}" method="post" onsubmit="return authenticateUser()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
        </form>
        <p class="mt-3 text-center">Don't have an account? <a href="/register">Register here</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The login and registering both use only username and password and i have absolutely no clue if i should share the bearer token or not, and if so, how.

I apologize in advance, i post for first time here.
Thank you!

**What I Tried:**

Implemented user authentication and registration functionality using Spring Security and JWT. Configured Spring Security to permit access to specific endpoints without authentication, while requiring authentication for others. Utilized the Fetch API in JavaScript to send Bearer Token in the Authorization header upon authentication.

**Expected Outcome:**

After a user successfully logs in or registers, the expectation is to be redirected to main.html with the appropriate Bearer Token in the Authorization header. This should allow access to main.html since the user is authenticated.

**Actual Outcome:**

Encountered a 403 Forbidden error when attempting to access main.html after successful registration or login. Despite having the Bearer Token, the server is not permitting access to the resource.

**Next Steps:**

Seeking assistance to identify the root cause of the 403 error and to ensure that authenticated users can successfully access main.html as intended.

Comment: You successfully signIn (and avoid having a 401 error); Now you need to request permission/access (e.g RBAC) to the resources you're looking for, to the admin/support who will provide your more power/access to your account, to allow you to continue. You code may have no issues. is commun to have different access control on different enpoints/resources